# Django celery run periodic task every day at specific time

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I want to run django celery periodic task every day at 6:30 pm

tasks.py

```
import celery
from datetime import datetime
@celery.task
def my_task():
    print(' task called ')
    print(datetime.now())
    return True
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
from tasks import my_task
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')
celery_instance = Celery('my_app')

celery_instance.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
celery_instance.autodiscover_tasks()

@celery_instance.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute=30, hour=18, day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun'),
        my_task.s(),
    )

    # when i try this it work of every 1 min
    sender.add_periodic_task(
         crontab(minute='*/1'),
         my_task.s(),
   )
```

when i hit celery -A app_name worker -B

the task is not hitting at 6:30 pm

Comment: I guess the task is scheduled at 4:30pm. (`hour=16` )

Comment: sorry that was my mistake while posting question but is issue is same i have updated

Comment: BTW: For a simpler implementation - if you are deploying to a unix server - use a Django command called by crontab on the target system. Also works with Docker containers.

Comment: What are your timezone settings? You are saying *every day* but you have excluded sunday...

Comment: timezone is TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `day_of_week` param.

Keep only `crontab(hour=18, minute=30)`  # It will run daily at 6:30 PM at your set timezone.